# Thymeleaf - how to populate input field if a value present?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot application with a flow like this.

- A new user register get registered
- He/She receives a verification email
- When the user clicks on the verification URL he/she will be redirected to the login page.

It's all good up to this point but what I want to do is when user gets to login page, I want to populate user's email into the email field and let user to enter his/her password to continue.

My email field looks like this:

```
<input type="email"
    id="userLoginFormEmail"
    class="form-control mb-4"
    th:field="*{email}"
    placeholder="Your email" required />
```

When the user gets redirected to login page, I'm adding user's email to model attribute like this:

```
model.addAttribute("userEmail", userEmail);
return "user/login";
```

So, how do I pre populate email field is `userEmail` attribute is not null?

**UPDATE**

I have an alert in the login page which appears fine when an activation url visited. It look like this

```
<div class="alert alert-info  mt-5" role="alert" th:if="${userEmail != null}">
    <strong>Your account is activated. Please login to proceed.</strong>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

So, `userEmail` works fine but still can't show it in the email field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, set the users email on the `userEmail` object (before the page is rendered).

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute `th:value="userEmail"` to the input field in the template